# User login encryption - Is SSL enough?

Tags: encryption, tls

We recently had a security engineer review our platform and they told us we need to encrypt the data when it's sent to the server.

However we're already sending the data with a SSL certificate. Which from my understanding, this handles all encryption for us.

There's a frontend react app & a backend api.
A user types in their credentials in the frontend and the frontend sends it to the backend. This sending part is the part in question.

The frontend & backend both have SSL enabled.

Is there something that I'm missing and/or that we should also be doing?

Comment: SSL only protects the transport of the data between client and server (or client and reverse proxy). It does not protect stored data at the server ("data at rest") nor data between a SSL terminating reverse proxy and the final server nor anything else. It is unclear what your application architecture is and what the security engineer referred too.

Comment: Even with the edit, it's not clear what the problem is that the engineer is seeing. I think you need to add more details around that, else we are guessing. Is TLS not being used? Is there something needed on top of TLS? Your first line talks about "to the server" but your edit says "sned to the backend".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL per se is deprecated and it would be very odd to directly encrypt user data with the certificate (or even the key it contains), but, assuming you mean you use TLS (probably though not necessarily through HTTPS): yes, that's fine for protecting the data in transit over the network. Of course, you need to make sure you *always* use TLS - no links in the chain where it's optional, no way to skip it, if your system is web-based use HSTS, etc. - but for securing data between the user and your servers, TLS (v1.2 or newer, as of 2021) is the gold standard, and adding extra encryption within it is almost 100% worthless (unless you're running one of the very few classes of apps where the server doesn't need to, and indeed should never, view the user data itself).

With that said, there are other places where you might need to encrypt data. Are you encrypting it at rest (in the database or file storage or whatever)? Are you encrypting it internally (that is, if you use multiple servers that communicate among themselves - even just a load balancer with app servers behind it - do you use TLS between them too)? Is the data being placed anywhere it might be exposed outside of TLS, such as in the URL (URLs are encrypted with HTTPS, but they're still much more likely to leak than message bodies) or if the data is sent over websockets or window messages or something? Are you in fact using the data directly or just passing it on to somebody else (e.g. credit card info to a payment processor, stored secrets in a password manager/vault of some kind, etc.)?

You also might be confusing encryption with other cryptographic operations. You mention user logins in the title; how are you storing user credentials? Most credentials and other long-lived secrets, such as passwords or API keys or refresh tokens, need to be hashed before being stored in the DB (hashed on the server after exiting the TLS tunnel, though; except in very rare cases there's no point hashing first on the client and even if you do you still must hash again on the server). Note that hashing for low-entropy secrets, like passwords, must use deliberately slow functions to be safe.

If you provide more information - both about your app, and the specific recommendations you got - that would help us help you more.

Comment: I've updated the question. Is this enough information?

Comment: Yeah, for the *transmission* of the credentials, HTTPS is fine (and indeed the industry standard for all but the very most sensitive sites). However, it's not enough to have HTTPS *enabled*, it needs to be *required*. The server should reject any request arriving over plain HTTP, instead redirecting to HTTPS, and you should implement HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS).